# Creating a New Table in Big Query from a log table and a reference table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new to big query and need to create a perm. table from a log file and a reference table.  I am new to this, and did something wrong but can't figure out why.  Please help.

log file (example)

-Event_Time,User_ID,Type

-1/1/2017,123_abc,a

-1/2/2017,123_bcd,b

-1/2/2017,123_abc,c

Reference Table (example)

-Type Partner

-a 1

-b 2

-c 3

-d 3

```
create table workarea.SummaryTable AS (
User_ID string,
TotalCount integer,
imps_time timestamp,
Partner integer)

insert into workarea.SummaryTable
select distinct User_ID,
COUNT(*) as TotalCount,
MIN(TIME) as imps_time,
SUM(case when Partner = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as 1,
SUM(case when Partner = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as 2,
SUM(case when Partner = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as 3

from workarea.logfile i
join workarea.referencetable r on i.Type=r.Type
where CID=10848805 
group by USER_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

> .. and did something wrong but can't figure out why

Below points of failure I have identified so far

1. `CREATE TABLE` statement is not available in BigQuery
   [`Data Manipulation Language`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax) allows you `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` only

You need to have table [`pre-created`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui#createtable) before you can manipulate with / insert data in it

2. Aliases cannot start with digits -

so below fragment is incorrect

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Partner = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 1,    
SUM(CASE WHEN Partner = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 2,    
SUM(CASE WHEN Partner = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 3
```

you should rather use something like

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Partner = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Partner_1,    
SUM(CASE WHEN Partner = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Partner_2,    
SUM(CASE WHEN Partner = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Partner_3
```

3. Some fields look like do not exist in referenced tables but you use them in final query: `time` in `MIN(time) as imps_time` and `CID` in `WHERE CID=10848805`
4. Schema of destination table has 4 fields - whereas schema of select statement has 6 fields. You should clear this out!! They must match!

Possible "solution" (BigQuery Standard SQL)

I assume (just for a sake of getting some progress here) the schema of your destination table in reality as something as below

```
User_ID STRING,
TotalCount INT64,
imps_time TIMESTAMP,
Partner_1 INT64,
Partner_2 INT64,
Partner_3 INT64
```

in this case - below query should produce correct result for insertion

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  User_ID,
  COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,
  MIN(Event_Time) AS imps_time,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Partner = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Partner_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Partner = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Partner_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Partner = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Partner_3
FROM `workarea.logfile` i
JOIN `workarea.referencetable` r ON i.Type=r.Type
-- WHERE CID=10848805 
GROUP BY USER_ID
```